# Different traceid between JMS producer and consumer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, micrometer-tracing

We have two component.
First component send JMS message and other component listen. We used to use Sleuth previously and traceid used to be same across component. Recently we migrated and use micrometer and we are facing issue of different traceid. Does anyone know how to resolve this.

Couldn't find any solution so far.

Comment: Can you show tracing configuration for micrometer ?